# mount CIFS share failed after FreeNAS server upgrade

Tags: mount, freenas, cifs

I upgraded a FreeNAS server from Ver 9.X to the latest 11.3.
Configuration has been saved prior the upgrade and restored on the new installation.
Currently, a remote Linux machine is unable to mount the FreeNAS shared folder as before.
Nothing has been changed on the remote Linux machine.

Mount command:
`mount -t cifs //192.168.0.6/Data /mnt/remotebackup -o username=xxx,password=yyy,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nounix,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770`

After reading some similar questions - I tried to add vers=3.0:
`mount -t cifs //192.168.0.6/Data /mnt/remotebackup -o username=xxx,password=yyy,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nounix,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=3.0`

Response:
mount error(95): Operation not supported

Since no change has been done on the remote Linux machine - I guess it is related to some change on the FreeNAS.

Remote Linux machine:                                                                                                                                                                              Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `sec=ntlm` is the most likely suspect - try without it.

Comment: Tried without ‘sec=ntlm’. Same result.

Comment: Hi, can someone try to solve that?